# Can I call fmod, the audio engine, with JavaScript in a web page?

Tags: javascript, fmod

Can I call fmod, the audio engine, with JavaScript in a web page? I can't find any documentation on this. The HTML 5 audio API is pathetic; I want more advanced audio options than it offers. So I'd like to use fmod if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this five years later because it shows up as a top result when you google "html5 FMOD".

As of this week, you *can* use FMOD with Javascript.

Here's the announcement:

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/28454-fmod-studio-api-now-available-for-html5/

There are a couple weird things about the API but hopefully that gets solved soon. I'm really excited about all the sound design possibilities this opens up.

Documentation:
https://www.fmod.com/docs/2.02/api/platforms-html5.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link in the answer is now broken. Here is a link to some docs: https://www.fmod.com/resources/documentation-api?version=2.02&page=platforms-html5.html

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use FMOD with JavaScript, at least not portably that I'm aware of. You may be able to hook DLLs and call into FMOD that way, I'm not sure if that's even possible with JavaScript though.

Your options for using FMOD on the web are:

- ActiveX, again here you would be hooking into DLLs, not a great idea.
- Native Client for Google Chrome, better option, but only for Chrome.
- Unity game engine, which has a web player and uses FMOD under the hood.